# AngularJS ng - repeat, ng - model on input text strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

i am new to AngularJS, i try and do the code below

```
var app = angular.module('SomeApp', []);

app.controller('QuotationController', function($scope) {

   $scope.init = function(){
     $scope.chargableDescription = [""];
     $scope.chargablePrice = [];
     $scope.chargableQuantity = [];
     $scope.chargableTotal = [];

   }

   $scope.chargableInput = function($last){

     if ( $last ) {
       $scope.chargableDescription.push([""]);
     }
   }
});
```

Basically, what i am trying to achieve here is to insert the whole group of input when user input something on the last chargableDescription field.

```
      <div class="chargable-group" ng-repeat="item in chargableDescription" >

            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label class="form-control-label" for="l2" id="chargable-label">Chargable Item</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9" id="chargable-header">
                 <textarea name="chargable[]" class="form-control dynamic chargable" placeholder="Chargable Description" ng-model="chargableDescription[$index]" ng-keypress="chargableInput($last)"> </textarea>
                 <br>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" name="chargable-price-1" placeholder="Chargable Price" ng-model="chargablePrice[$index]">
                 <br>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="chargable-quantity-1" placeholder="Chargable Quantity" ng-model="chargableQuantity[$index]">
                 <br>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" name="chargable-total-1" placeholder="Chargable Total" readonly ng-model="chargableTotal[$index]" >
            </div>

      </div>
```

It does the trick, however, i wonder why when i do any input on the textarea, the cursor will be gone once i input a character.
How to remove this behaviour and what would be the factor that causing this behavior?

UPDATE :

SOLVED 
I added ng-model-options = { updateOn : 'blur' } and it seems like it solves the issue

Comment: Please delete the question, as it will always show in unanswered otherwise, and it will waste anyone's time when they start reading it, in order to solve it. Or else, write [Solved] in the title itself.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me https://plnkr.co/IV9t4fhln5v3l81NHaPC

What's your Angular version?

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('SomeApp', []);

  app.controller('QuotationController', function($scope) {

    $scope.init = function() {
      $scope.chargableDescription = [""];
      $scope.chargablePrice = [];
      $scope.chargableQuantity = [];
      $scope.chargableTotal = [];

    }

    $scope.chargableInput = function($last) {

      if ($last) {
        $scope.chargableDescription.push([""]);
      }
    }

    $scope.init();
  });


})();
```

Comment: I can see it is working on the link above, but it doesnt work with me.
But why you add $scope.init(); after the logic? Isn't that refresh the initial value? I added ng-model-options = { updateOn : 'blur' }  and it works just nice, but i do wonder why.
Do you know why?
Thank you for your answer and hope you can explain to me, cause i am really new to AngularJS.

@Karl  San Gabriel